# Implement JColor Picker in Jtable Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, color-picker

How would I go to implement, Jquery-color-picker into my Jtable for the field colourCode. The colourCode is a hex code supplied by a Json string. I did some research about Jtable (input). but it led me to a dead end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#EventTypeTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Table of EventType',
                columnResizable: false,
                columnSelectable: false,
                actions: {
                    listAction: 'Admin/GetEventTypeList',
                    createAction: 'Admin/CreateEventType',
                    updateAction: 'Admin/UpdateEventType',
                    deleteAction: 'Admin/DeleteEventType'
                },
                fields: {
                    EventTypeId: {
                        key: true,
                        list: false
                    },
                    EventTypeName: {
                        title: 'Event Type',
                        width: '40%'
                    },
                    colourCode: {
                        title: 'Event Color',
                        width: '40%',
                        input: $(function () { $('input').ColorPicker(options);}),
                    },
                    isSystemEventType: {
                        title: 'System Constraint',
                        width: '20%',
                        list: false,
                        create: false,
                        edit: false
                    }
                }
            });
            $('#EventTypeTableContainer').jtable('load');
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of the ['input'](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#fopt-input) property and the ['formCreated'](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#event-formCreated) event to achieve this.

In the input function add an 'id' to a normal text input.

```
input: function (data) {
    if (data.record) {
        return '<input id="color" type="text" value="data.record.color">';
    } else {
        return '<input id="color" type="text">';
    }
}
```

Next in the 'formCreated' event initialize the color picker.

```
formCreated: function (event, data) {
    $('#color').ColorPicker(options);
}
```